# Viewing flash images or files in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

its is not so easy to display flash files the way you display images and videos in rails. pls Does anyone have an idea how i can display flash images in rails. im using rails 3.0.8.rc4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display flash content in Rails you would just embed it in your view files. Erb is really just HTML with some nice ways to include typical Ruby code in them. Why don't you try embedding swf content as you would normally?

If you have any other questions feel free to ask.